# On rectangular section beam properties of plate stiffeners

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, beam, vibration, stiffness

I am trying to understand the expression of the vertical dynamic stiffness $K_T$ and the rotational dynamic stiffness $K_r$ which appears in this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022460X86801286) where they consider a semi-infinite plate periodically stiffened and simply-supported at $y=0$ and $y=L_y$ :
[image]

The uncoupled flexural and torsional motions of the stiffeners are governed by:
$$E_sI_s\frac{\partial^4u}{\partial y^4}+\rho_s A_s\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = P_s\sin(k_yy)e^{i\omega t}$$
$$-E_s\Gamma_s\frac{\partial^4\theta}{\partial y^4}+G_s J_s\frac{\partial^2\theta}{\partial y^2}-\rho I_p\frac{\partial^2\theta}{\partial t^2} = -T_s\sin(k_yy)e^{i\omega t}$$
$P_s\sin(k_yy)e^{i\omega t}$ and $T_s\sin(k_yy)e^{i\omega t}$ represent distributed transverse forces and torsional moments that excite the stiffeners.
Assuming $u=u_s\sin(k_yy)e^{i\omega t}$ and $\theta=\theta_s\sin(k_yy)e^{i\omega t}$, the two equations yield:
$$
u_s = \frac{P_s}{E_sI_sk_y^4-\rho_s A_s\omega^2}=\frac{P_s}{K_T},\quad \theta_s = \frac{T_s}{E_s\Gamma_sk_y^4+GJ_sk_y^2-\rho I_p\omega^2} = \frac{T_s}{K_R}
$$
with the dynamic stiffnesses:
$$K_T = E_sI_sk_y^4-\rho_s A_s\omega^2,\quad K_r = E_s\Gamma_sk_y^4+G_sJ_sk_y^2-\rho_p I_p\omega^2$$
The $s$ subscript stand for stiffener while $p$ stand for plate. And:

- $E_sI_s$ the flexural stiffness,
- $\rho_s A_s$ the mass per unit length,
- $E_s\Gamma_s$ the torsion-bending stiffness (or warping constant?),
- $G_sJ_s$ the St.Venant torsional stiffness,
- $\rho_p I_p$ the moment of inertia per unit length about the plate mid-plane axis.

I'm having a hard time finding formulas for $\Gamma_s$, $J_s$, $I_s$ and $I_p$.

If someone could provide those as well as the proper references (books/papers with the pages) specifying each of these parameters (especially $\Gamma_s$ and $J_s$) it would be great !

Comment: Check out Timoshenko - good books on stress & strain

Comment: Your paper is behind a paywall so I can't read it, but from the equations you give it looks like $I_s$, $I_p$, $J_s$, and $\Gamma_s$ are the standard quantities (which depend on the cross section shape) for any (Euler-Timoshenko) beam formulation. The only  messy one is the warping constant, which is usually calculated by semi-empirical formulas rather than from "exact" theory (and my personal view is that "if you need to include the value of the  warping constant in your beam formulation at all, the structure probably isn't really behaving like a beam anyway").

Comment: ... the effect of "warping" on the coupling between torsion and bending deformation is sensitive to the way the ends of the beam are constrained, and if you really care about that, you should make a 3D model with the physically correct restraints applied to the ends, not a beam model. The reason is that torsion-bending coupling is one of the few situations where St. Venant's Principle (i.e. that the exact details of the structural constraints only have local effects not global ones) does **not** apply.

Comment: I've deleted my previous answer as alephzero rightly pointed out the shear strain (Greek Gamma) does not fit into the equation. I suggest listing all parameters, with units indicated would help.

Comment: Thank you for your feedbacks ! I updated the post and added how $\gamma$ and $J_s$ end up in the relations. Looking at the paper, it seems that the semi-infinite plate is simply supported on its width, the stiffener is then considered as a simply supported beam with a harmonic force and moment field. I though that maybe they were generic formulas for $J_s$ and $Gamma_s$ but it seems that it will take more research on my part. I'm really not familiar with those two notations and physical meaning.

Comment: What is "k_y" and its unit? You can get the idea of J_s (torsion constant) from this article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_constant. As you can see it is not described by a generic formula. Also, it depends on the shape of the structure/element in consideration.

Comment: @r13 Thank you for the feedback ! $k_y$ is a wavenumber which in this case can be expressed as $\frac{\pi}{L_y}$.

Comment: This article, while concerning the open section of cold-formed steel, provides the method to calculate Cw. Read on. http://kssc.or.kr/wonmun/KSSC_3_2007_7_4_297(C).pdf